# nao estou conseguindo ir para o frame "main2". VBA e SelleniumWrapper

Tags: html, vba, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

estou tentando acessar uma pagina na web e manipular seus controles via **VBA** e **Selennium Wrapper**, porém, estes controles estão dentro de um frame com o "**name = main2**", segue o código **VBA:**

```
Sub z()
Dim objCollection
    Dim numeroPregao, dataAssinatura, uasg, item, val, m
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim ULogin As Boolean, ieForm
    Dim MyPass As String, MyLogin As String
    Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver


    driver.Start "chrome", "http://comprasnet.gov.br"
    driver.setImplicitWait 5000
    driver.Open "/acesso.asp?url=/Livre/Ata/ConsultaAta00.asp"


    driver.SwitchToFrame ("main2")
    driver.FindElementByName("dt_ini").SendKeys "25/11/2015"



End Sub
```

agradeço desde já!
Feliz natal e um prospero ano novo a todos!

Comment: se achou útil vote na resposta! rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui selecionar o frame e fazer a interação, o código ficou assim:

```
Set objCollection = driver.findElementByCssSelector("frame[name='main2']")
    driver.SwitchToFrame (objCollection)

    driver.FindElementByName("dt_ini").SendKeys "25/11/2015"
```